# How to merge vector buildings height layer with raster DEM to get solar maps in r.sun in Grass GIS?

Tags: raster, grass-gis, vector, merge, solar-radiation

Welcome, this is my first post.
I have vector layer with buildings heights and vector/raster DEM file.
I need to create solar maps with sun radiance values on the roof (and on surface, ofc). I am trying merge buildings with DEM, but I dont know how excatly to do it. I converted vector buildings to raster, made pixels outside buildings to null, and tried merge this file in 'r.mapcalc'. I think I should use 'if' function, but I dont know to how. Could anybody help me with it? It is possible to make flat surface in DEM under buidings in order to place buildings there?

Comment: please see my answer. I think a good start for you is to Google mentioned tools to start learn them

Answer (score 1):

The solution i would use to solve this problem is:

1. Rasterize the building vector layer on the same extent/resolution as the DEM to get a raster with height values where are Buildings and NoData elsewhere (with v.to.rast.attribute for example)
2. Performing an addition of this two raster with a raster Calculator (r.mapcalc for example)

This would result in a DEM where the building height will be add to the ground height where there is a building.

Answer (score 0):

Generall solution for this kind of tasks:

Every desent GIS SW have tools that extract raster value into vector layer. They will attach on single button click  to every point from the vector layer the corresponding underlaying raster value (kind of interpolation).

Now, building is polygon of lines. These kind of tools work usually on points. There are several approaches:

1. Work on building vertices
2. Transform building to single point at his centroid
3. Break each line to several points until the desired resolution

Comment: Thanks. I try to export raster to vector, and merge this. Do you know how to merge raster with 'if' function in GRASS GIS?

Comment: @mrkkr91 I think you not totally understood the whole concept of extract raster value to vector layer. It's a build in tool in gis sw so you don't need to write code or sql. you just need to supply raster and vector layer and make sure the vector layer is points.

Comment: I'm not sure we both understand each other. Should I convert raster DEM to vector in e.g. qgis/grass, and later vector polygon buildings to point building vertices?

Comment: @mrkkr91 You don't touch the raster layer, you need to work with vector layer of points, you have buildings, they probably polygons so convert them in 1 of the 3 ways I mentioned in my answer to points.

Comment: Ok, I understand. If I would have buildings converted to points what I have to do later to merge this to DEM?

Comment: @mrkkr91 in the tool it will ask you to supply the raster layer, then the vector layer, then click and that's all. now you can open the vector layer as attribute table and you will see new column with raster value at this point. create new column in the vector layer, put their the sum of point height and raster value and you have the total MSL height...

Comment: What specific tool do you have in mind?

Comment: the one of arcgis its not free source

Comment: Could you give me a name this tool?

Comment: http://webhelp.esri.com/arcgisdesktop/9.3/index.cfm?TopicName=extract_values_to_points

Comment: @mrkkr91 is this what you looked for?

Comment: This is usefull, but I think not exactly in this case. I want to put on DEM raster buildings vector layer. I want to have one raster file with DEM and buildings.

Comment: @mrkkr91 You want on the raster file format, have for the locations where there is a vector data of height, to put it on the raster? I think it's impossible. You need to build your own custom raster data. Usually it's not the direction used rather one I gave. Raster data is something we have like SRTM and that's it...

Comment: What do you think about this: I try to convert vector data with buildings to raster, and later try to put this raster on DEM. I think this is possible, maybe e.g. in raster calculator with some function? Do you think it will be real?

Comment: it's technically possible (look for tool merging rasters). but I think this is not the right solution for this kind of analysis. when we once needed add raster values to buildings height - we used the solution I gave as best practice.

Comment: ok. thanks. do you know how to use 'if' function to merge rasters?

Comment: If there is no build in tool inside gis sw, so you probably will need to manually create this raster data - it's code...